# rsync vs SyncML (Funambol)

Tags: rsync, syncml

I would like some idea about how rsync compares to SyncML/Funambol, especially when it comes to bandwidth, sync over unstable network and multiple clients to one server.

This is to sync several mobile devices with a directory structure of growing text-files.  (Se we essentially want as much as possible on the server, and inconsistent files is not really a problem, also we know where changes originates).

So far, it seems Funambol doesn't compress, doesn't handle partial updates, and it is difficult to handle interruptions in a file-transfer.

I know rsync doesn't go through the server, but I don't quite see how that is a disadvantage.

Comment: Why would you want to use SyncML/Funambol for this? AFAIK, it's designed not for arbitrary data, but for contacts, email, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olav,

rsync can:

- **Compress** the data (as you said) - thus gaining better performances over the net.
- Synchronize **only the newest data** within each file - thus, once again, saving time.
- Can be ran by **multiple users** at the same time. It's a very basic backup software behavior.
- And one of my favorites: work over a secure shell.

You might want to check [Rsyncrypto](http://rsyncrypto.lingnu.com/index.php/Home_Page), for compressing **and** encrypting at the same time.

Dotan